# How to delete local notification if current datetime is past the scheduled datetime?

Tags: ios, notifications, localnotification

I am using local notification for my app.

Notification is set for particular time interval like daily, weekly, monthly and it also have completion time date.

So how can i delete notification when it's completion time date pass away?

For example

If I set tomorrow as completion time date and notification repeat interval daily then  this notification will show only today and tomorrow, not after that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just schedule individual notifications in this case. For example if you want to have a notification today and tomorrow, that's two notifications. A "completion time" is not available in the [UILocalNotification API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Please note that you can have at most 64 scheduled notifications at the same time. So the user has to open the app at least every 64 notifications, so that your app is able to schedule new notifications. (If you have more than 64 local notifications, all but the soonest firing 64 notifications are discarded.)